# How to create and push a submodule using TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, git-submodules, tortoisegit

How to create a submodule using TortoiseGit in my local repository? And how to push the created submodule to the main Git repository?

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a new repository for that submodule and commit one commit at least in that submodule if submodule does not exist yet
2. Use TortoiseGit -> Submodule Add...
   [image]
3. Fill the URL of source repository(the submodule) and the target Path (related path)
   [image]
4. Commit

   [image]
5. Push

   [image]

Comment: Suppose I have a sample and a library, should they both be in a different repository, or can they be in a single one, and the sub module can be to a path within, of the library folder?

Comment: Most of the time, they are in different repository.

Comment: They can be in a single one, but no one does that.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: Oddly, in the dialog box you have to manually type in the name of the [last] sub directory name.  Just selecting an empty one that exists will not work...

Answer (score 1):

A submodule is just a normal git repository. So you can create a new git repository for your submodule an then add it as submodule in your existing project.

Comment: so, do we need to maintain two separate repositories and call one in another repository

Comment: In CVS & SVN we can create submodule without creating seperate repository for it. Do we have this kind of feature in GIT.

Comment: IIRC, no. The submodule should be exist first. Git needs the URL and the commit sha-1 value which is recorded by the super repository.